# What does the representation category of the knot group know?

Tags: knot-theory

Let $K, K'$ be knots in $S^3$, and $T, T'$ the boundaries of their tubular neighborhoods.

Recall that by theorems of Waldhausen, and Gordon and Luecke, one knows the following: an isomorphism $[\pi_1(T) \to \pi_1(S^3 \setminus K)] \cong [(\pi_1(T') \to \pi_1(S^3 \setminus K')]$ implies that $K$ and $K'$ are isotopic.

> > Suppose the category of linear representations of $[\pi_1(T) \to \pi_1(S^3 \setminus K)]$ is equivalent to the category of linear representations of $[\pi_1(T') \to \pi_1(S^3 \setminus K')]$. Are $K$ and $K'$ isotopic?

$$ $$

Note: In a previous version of this question, I asked whether this is possible if you interpret the category above as a tensor category; in the comments it is pointed out that then, yes, at least if you allow big representations.  But, now I realize that in fact I don't have the tensor product structure.

Comment: What do you mean by linear representations of a morphism of groups?

Comment: representation of one, representation of the other, morphism between them compatible with the map of groups.

Comment: Do you allow infinite-dimensional representations?  If so, the answer should be trivially yes, since if you allow infinite dimensional representations, a (possibly infinite) discrete group $G$ is the group of symmetric monoidal endomorphisms of the unique (up to isomorphism) symmetric monoidal exact functor $\mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb C}(G) \to \mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb C}$, and homomorphisms $G \to H$ are uniquely determined by the corresponding symmetric monoidal functors $\mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb C}(H) \to \mathrm{Rep}_{\mathbb C}(G)$.

Comment: If the knot is hyperbolic then the hyperbolic representation is faithful, so maybe infinite-dimensional representations aren't needed, at least for hyperbolic knots.

Comment: Every knot group admits a faithful finite-dimensional representation. Over the integers this is a theorem of Przytycki--Wise, though I have a feeling that over the reals it was proved by Kronheimer--Mrowka.

Comment: Let's simplify to consider just the representation category of the fundamental group (this suffices to distinguish prime knots). Let me ask you whether this category can recover the finite quotients of the group? For some knots, such as the figure 8 knot, the finite quotients of the fundamental group determine the knot. Each representation factoring through a finite group $G$ should give a sub-category $Rep(G)$ . If one could recover the finite group from this sub-fusion category, then maybe one could recover the finite quotients from the representation category?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So long as I allow myself infinite size representations, and writing $\mathbb{Z}[G]-mod$ for representations of $G$ in $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, then so long as I have the forgetful functor

$$\mathbb{Z}[G]-mod \to \mathbb{Z}-mod$$

I can recover $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ as endomorphisms of this functor.

In general, one cannot recover $G$ even from $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, [even for finite groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3062112) $G$.

However, as it turns out, knot groups are known to be left orderable, and it is known that for left orderable groups, the only units in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ are the obvious ones, from which $G$ can be recovered.